# Cutting the text by regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have sample data like this:

```
<o:-200> Text1
<o:7> Text2
<o:218> Text3
<o:325> Text4
```

What I want to do:

1) Get number from tag (-200, 7, etc.)
2) Add value to this number (e.x. + 100)
3) Changed number replace with whole tag

Output:

```
-100 Text1
107 Text2
318 Text3
425 Text4
```

That's my code:

```
    String s;
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("<o:(-?[0-9]+)>");
    Matcher m = p1.matcher("<o:-200> ABC\n<o:7> ASDQWE\n<o:218> 12345.67\n<o:325> ASDFGD asdfsdf\n");
    StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()){
        m.appendReplacement(s1, String.valueOf(100 + Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))));
    }
    s = s1.toString().replaceAll("<o:\\b(\\d+)\\b>", "$1" );
    System.out.println(s);
```

But my output is:

```
-100 Text1
107 Text2
318 Text3
425
```

But I want whole text. ReplaceAll doesn't work (changing all tags with 1st value found).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Look into the documentation of the method [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-). It contains an example that clearly shows you one line missing:

```
while(...) {...}
m.appendTail(s1); // <- this one
```

Comment: If you change your pattern to `"(<o:(-?[0-9]+)>)"` and call parseInt on m.group(2), then you can dispense with the call to replaceAll().